# Update APK from URL Android Without Google Play

Tags: apk, auto-update, android-install-apk, android-update-app

I Have a code that detect if a "Package-Name" is installed or not, and download it from URL if not.

Everything is good for now, But I want to Update The APK from the server and the App detect if a new version is available , And Prompt the user to download it, and uninstall the old version.

How Can I Do That with this code :

- I'm Using facebook-lite app as example in this*

Hope there is is an example for better understanding, Thank You.

```
    MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    ///// check if package name is installed //////////

    final String YOUR_PACKAGE = "com.facebook.lite";
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
    try {
    applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(YOUR_PACKAGE, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
          if (applicationInfo == null) {

    ///// If Not installed it will open your app directly from Url
    Update("https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqqbp5eazfs6hto/facebook.apk?dl=1");

    } else {
     // Open the app If Installed
    Intent LaunchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(YOUR_PACKAGE);
                startActivity(LaunchIntent);

            }
        }
    });
    ///// =*=*=**=*==*=*=**=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*

    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public void Update(final String apkurl) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
        String result = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(apkurl);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");

                c.connect();

                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "facebook.apk");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "facebook.apk")),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                result = "Update error! " + e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        }.execute();

    }

    }
```